# Did Korach's controversy "endure"?

Tags: machlokes, korach

The Mishnah says:

> Every controversy that is *leshem shamayim* -- for the sake of Heaven -- will endure.  But one that is not for the sake of Heaven will not endure. Which is a controversy that is for the sake of Heaven? The controversy of Hillel and Shammai. And which is a controversy that is not for the sake of Heaven? The controversy of Korach and all his followers. [Pirkei Avot 5:17]

Sure, Korach's timing and his motives were bad, but his controversy *did* endure.  A “controversy that endures” is one that is worthy of resulting in permanent change. His point was ultimately upheld.  The priests, the Levites, the Sadducees, the Jewish aristocracy all lost power after the Second Temple was destroyed.  Spiritual power became vested in the rabbis, who rise to their position thanks only to their own merit.  The kohanim and leviim have only ceremonial positions.  So, in that sense, Korach’s controversy did “endure”.  His descendants did well.  His three sons composed eleven of the psalms [Ps. 42, 44-49, 84-85, 87-88] and the prophet Samuel was his descendant.

What am I missing?

Comment: When the Beis haMikdosh will be rebuilt, the kohanim and leviim will return to their positions.

Comment: *A “controversy that endures” is one that is worthy of resulting in permanent change.* Whence this definition?

Comment: From the word "endures".  Its outcome is long-range.

Comment: "His point was ultimately upheld". In parashas Korach, G-d clearly shows what His plan was. Korach and the others were "wiped away". Would this be so if G-d knew that the point of Korach was ultimately upheld?

Comment: Korach wanted prestige and power.  He failed in that.  But he disguised his motive by telling Moses "We are all equal before God.  Why are you lording it over us?".  *That* point endured.  Also, the last Lubavitcher Rebbe said that his quest for high spiritual office was, in and of itself, a positive thing; that the story teaches us that we should desire and yearn for the highest ideals.; that the end is good even if the means are not.  *That* point also endured.

Comment: Korach's controversy ended immediately with the demise of Korach and did not endure. The controversy was not about what to do when we are placed in the unfortunate temporary circumstance of not having a Mishkan/Temple. That's not what Korach was talking about. He would say that there should never be a hierarchy even under ideal circumstances - this view was rejected and did not endure

Comment: Also not clear how his descendants are relevant to the question of his controversy enduring.

Comment: It was not leshem shamayim

Comment: A dear friend of mine who is a Catholic deacon said that a really good heresy never really goes away. It will just keep popping back up from different authors or communities throughout time.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the [weeds](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135552/did-korachs-controversy-endure#comment450938_135552) on whether today's rabbinical hierarchy reflects  or validates Korach's position, I think you're using an overly expansive definition of "will not endure." The very fact that Korach's story is recorded in Torah refutes the interpretation that nothing at all endured of the controversy. The [Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura%20on%20Pirkei%20Avot%205:17:1) to the mishna offers two narrower definitions, namely that Korach did not survive and his selfish aims were not achieved:

> **Every argument that is for [the sake of] heaven's name, it is destined (literally, its end is) to endure:** That is to say that the
> [parties to] the argument are destined to endure and not perish, as
> with the argument between Hillel and Shammai, [whereby] neither the
> students of the School of Hillel nor the students of the School of
> Shammai perished. But Korach and his congregation perished. And I
> heard the explanation of “its end” is its purpose that is sought from
> its subject. And [with] the argument which is for the sake of Heaven,
> the purpose and aim that is sought from that argument is to arrive at
> the truth, and this endures; like that which they said, "From a
> dispute the truth will be clarified," and as it became elucidated from
> the argument between Hillel and Shammai - that the law was like the
> school of Hillel. And [with] argument which is not for the sake of
> Heaven, its desired purpose is to achieve power and the love of
> contention, and its end will not endure; as we found in the argument
> of Korach and his congregation - that their aim and ultimate intent
> was to achieve honor and power, and the opposite was [achieved].